# Point of throwing different exception

Tags: java, exception

I found this example:

```
try {
    // some code
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw e;
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the point of having two separate blocks which both throw exception?

Would this code make same effect?

```
try {
    // some code
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely no point in rethrowing alone. But sometimes you may want to do something like logging, but still *not* catch the exception. Then you could first `catch` the exception, and then, within your catch block, do the things to be done and rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. The point of having two different `catch` blocks is so that the program can handle different errors in different ways. Further, by splitting the code into two blocks, the original code maintains the original exception type to be caught by a different method. In this case, however, since they are both doing the same thing (rethrowing the exception) you *could* combine into a single `catch(Exception e)` but this is not recommended. You should always be as specific as possible when catch exceptions. Since the `Exception` class is the parent of all exceptions, including `FileNotFoundException`, it is almost always bad practice to catch `Exception` alone.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have read a file from the file system and then save some data to the Database. When you try to read the file there is an error due file not found or permission. So you want to log and exit from the flow not continue to save to the database. But when reading is a success you check the connection to the database and the connection is correct. Then you go to the insert to the table but there is an issue related to some duplicated records in the catch of the SQL you rollback and log.

---

```
try {
    // Read from a file
    // Save to the database
}catch(IOException e) {
    // log
}catch(SQLException e) {
   // rollback
   // log
}finally {
   // close IO resources
   // close SQL resources
}
```